# Alternative to create_proc_entry() and read_proc in Linux kernel code

Tags: c, linux-kernel, procfs

A few years ago, Linux 3.8 was ported to the TI-nSpire graphing calculator (https://github.com/tangrs/linux). While some of the changes were upstreamed, most of them were not. I've been rewriting the patches for the latest kernel sources, but I'm stuck on a deprecated function:
`create_proc_entry()`

I got two GCC error messages relating to this. The first one I fixed by changing `create_proc_entry(BOOT1_PROCFS_NAME, 0644, NULL);` to `proc_create_data(BOOT1_PROCFS_NAME, 0644, NULL, NULL, NULL);`
 (If there is something better, please let me know.)
The second error,

```
arch/arm/mach-nspire/boot1.c:37:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct proc_dir_entry’
boot1_proc_entry->read_proc = boot1_read;
```

I have been unable to fix. I looked at the git history where `read_proc_t *read_proc;` (part of `struct proc_dir_entry`; then located in `include/linux/proc_fs.h`, now located in `fs/proc/internal.h`) was removed (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3cb5bf1bf947d325fcf6e9458952b51cfd7e6677#diff-a2f17c99c50d86d5160c8f7f0261fbbd), expecting to see something else put in it's place, but that is not the case. Instead, it was deprecated along with `create_proc_entry()`.

So how should I rewrite the line `boot1_proc_entry->read_proc = boot1_read;` (full file here: https://github.com/tangrs/linux/blob/nspire/arch/arm/mach-nspire/boot1.c) so that it will compile with current kernel sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `proc_create_data` has prototype

```
struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *, umode_t,
                       struct proc_dir_entry *,
                       const struct file_operations *,
                       void *);
```

and its 4th parameter is a structure of **file operations**.

For specify, how data should be read from the file, you need to setup `.read` field of that structure: this is a **replacement** for (old) assigning `read_proc` field in the `proc_dir_entry` object.

While signature for `.read` function (callback) is very generic:

```
ssize_t (*read) (struct file * file, char __user * buf, size_t size, loff_t * ppos);
```

Linux kernel has several helpers for implement this function for simple cases.

E.g., if you want to "map" some buffer as file's content, you may use `simple_read_from_buffer` helper:

```
ssize_t my_read (struct file * file, char __user * buf, size_t size, loff_t * ppos)
{
    return simple_read_from_buffer(
        buf, size, ppos, // first 3 arguments are just ones for .read function
        NSPIRE_BOOT1_VIRT_BASE, // address of the buffer's start
        NSPIRE_BOOT1_SIZE // size of the buffer
    )
}
```

The rest of code:

```
// Define file operations for given file.
static const struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE, // This is useful almost in any case
    .read = my_read, // Setup .read function
};

// And create the file itself
entry = proc_create_data(BOOT1_PROCFS_NAME, 0644, NULL, &my_fops, NULL);
```